# My Simple JavaScript code isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have this simple and basic code that I did on JSFiddle
It doesn't seem to work.
What I want it to do is to change the innerHTML of the head2 id to the text in the JavaScript code

Let me know what you think!

P.S this is in JSFiddle so I didn't link the JavaScript file into my HTML as they already link it I believe

```js
function clickMe() {
 var hehe = document.getElementById('head2');
    hehe.innerHTML = "<strong>I changed the heading!</strong>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is heading one
</h1>
<h2 id="head2">
This is heading two
</h2>
<input value="Click me!" type="button" onclick="clickMe">
```

Comment: `onclick="clickMe()"` instead of `onclick="clickMe"`. Functions are called via `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `onclick="clickMe"` to `onclick="clickMe()"`. You forgot the parenthesis

```js
function clickMe() 
{
    var hehe = document.getElementById('head2');
    hehe.innerHTML = "<strong>I changed the heading!</strong>";
}
```

```html
<h1>This is heading one</h1>
<h2 id="head2">This is heading two</h2>
 
<input value="Click me!" type="button" onclick="clickMe()">
```

Comment: Thanks! This code snippet works in stackoverflow but no on jsfiddle or notepad. Do you know what it could be that's stopping the code from working?

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses in the 'onclick' for your function name

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative. This is just my preference, but I prefer to handle the events in JavaScript, instead of adding the `onClick` attribute to nodes. Here is an alternative.

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener("click", clickMe);
function clickMe() {
 var hehe = document.getElementById('head2');
    hehe.innerHTML = "<strong>I changed the heading!</strong>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is heading one
</h1>
<h2 id="head2">
This is heading two
</h2>
<input value="Click me!" id="myButton" type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

just use onclick="clickMe()" instead of using onclick="clickMe"

```js
function clickMe() {
 var hehe = document.getElementById('head2');
    hehe.innerHTML = "<strong>I changed the heading!</strong>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is heading one
</h1>
<h2 id="head2">
This is heading two
</h2>
<input value="Click me!" type="button" onclick="clickMe()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "()" after a call to a **Javascript function**. This is the correct code. Enjoy :) !

```js
function clickMe() {
 var hehe = document.getElementById('head2');
    hehe.innerHTML = "<strong>I changed the heading!</strong>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is heading one
</h1>
<h2 id="head2">
This is heading two
</h2>
<input value="Click me!" type="button" onclick="clickMe()">
```

Comment: Thanks! I literally just figured that out before logging back on :P